# Replace a value conditionally while ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a variable called `region` with the regions of the world. The variable `Country` includes the country name.

Sometimes `Country` has `NA` values but the region is still included. I want to change the region from "Europe" to "France" only for France, without changing anything else in the `region` variable. However, when I run the code below, `region` changes to be `NA` for all of the observations with `NA` in `Country`.

```
data <- data|>  
          mutate(region = case_when(
                            data$`Country` == "France" ~ "France",
                            data$`Country` != "France" ~ region)
                            )
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: When using `mutate` we do not use `$` unless calling a different dataframe than the one you are dealing with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `region` will only be returned when `Country != "France"` is `TRUE`, which isn’t the case when `Country` is `NA`. You can address this by including a test for `NA`s in your condition:

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
  mutate(region = case_when(
    Country == "France" ~ "France",
    Country != "France" | is.na(Country) ~ region
  ))
```

Or using `ifelse()`:

```
data |>
  mutate(region = ifelse(
    Country == "France" & !is.na(Country),
    "France", 
    region
  ))
```

Or, in dplyr v1.1.0 or higher, you can use the `.default` argument of `case_when()`:

```
data |>
  mutate(region = case_when(
    Country == "France" ~ "France",
    .default = region
  ))
```

Result from any of these approaches:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Country     region
  <chr>       <chr> 
1 France      France
2 Germany     Europe
3 <NA>        Asia  
4 South Korea Asia
```

*Example data:*

```
data <- tibble(
  Country = c("France", "Germany", NA, "South Korea"),
  region = c("Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a cleaner solution, but you can always try:

```r
data|>  
  mutate(region = case_when(
    Country == "France" ~ "France",
    Country != "France" ~ region,
    is.na(Country) ~ region)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ifelse` and check for NA values and not equal to `"France"` in `Country`.

```
data |>  
  mutate(region = ifelse(is.na(Country) | Country != "France", region, Country)) -> data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data %>%
   mutate(region =case_match(Country,'France'~'France',.default = region))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Country     region
  <chr>       <chr> 
1 France      France
2 Germany     Europe
3 NA          Asia  
4 South Korea Asia 

data %>%
   mutate(region1 = coalesce(`is.na<-`(region, Country == 'France'), Country))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Country     region region1
  <chr>       <chr>  <chr>  
1 France      Europe France 
2 Germany     Europe Europe 
3 NA          Asia   Asia   
4 South Korea Asia   Asia
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ifelse()` instead of `case_when()`:

```
data<- data %>%  
  mutate(region = ifelse(Country =="France","France",region)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and confirm what you mentioned in your answer. The term `& !is.na(Country)` must be added.

Comment: This answer has been already posted. See the accepted answer.